# What is the appropriate way to return a variable with a different type than the variable being reduced?

Tags: typescript, reduce

I have the following code:

```js
interface ICartItemResponse {
    sku: string;
    priceChange: boolean;
    price: number;
    total: number;
    label: string;
}

type TCartTotalType = "shipping" | "tax" | "discount";

interface ICartTotal {
    type: TCartTotalType;
    title: string;
    price: number;
};

const promo: ICartItemResponse[] = [/* Some data */];

const availablePromos: ICartTotal[] = promo.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return [
        ...acc,
        {
            type: "discount",
            title: cur.label,
            price: cur.total
        }
    ]
}, []);
```

The code above throws two erros:

1. In the `availablePromos` definition:

```
const availablePromos: ICartTotal[]
Type 'ICartItemResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'ICartTotal[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

2. In the previous and current values (`acc` and `cur`, respectively):

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: ICartItemResponse, currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => ICartItemResponse, initialValue: ICartItemResponse): ICartItemResponse', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: never[], cur: ICartItemResponse) => { type: "discount"; title: string; price: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: ICartItemResponse, currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => ICartItemResponse'.
      Types of parameters 'acc' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
        Type 'ICartItemResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'never[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: never[], currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => never[], initialValue: never[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: never[], cur: ICartItemResponse) => { type: "discount"; title: string; price: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: never[], currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => never[]'.
      Type '{ type: "discount"; title: string; price: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
        Type '{ type: "discount"; title: string; price: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I notice it was possible to "solve" both errors in two different ways:

1. Specifying the type of previous value but not of the current value

```js
(acc: ICartTotal[], cur)
```

Notice that if I specify the type of the current value (which is indeed being infered) with the same infered type. Throws the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: ICartItemResponse, currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => ICartItemResponse, initialValue: ICartItemResponse): ICartItemResponse', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: ICartTotal[], cur: ICartItemResponse) => { type: string; title: string; price: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: ICartItemResponse, currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => ICartItemResponse'.
      Types of parameters 'acc' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
        Type 'ICartItemResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'ICartTotal[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: ICartTotal[], currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => ICartTotal[], initialValue: ICartTotal[]): ICartTotal[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: ICartTotal[], cur: ICartItemResponse) => { type: string; title: string; price: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: ICartTotal[], currentValue: ICartItemResponse, currentIndex: number, array: ICartItemResponse[]) => ICartTotal[]'.
      Type '{ type: string; title: string; price: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ICartTotal[]'.
        Type '{ type: string; title: string; price: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ICartTotal'.
          Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ICartTotalType'.
```

2. Asserting the type of initial value

```
[] as ICarttotal[]
```

This one works fine, but if I also combine this with the first approach, throws the same error as in the last point.

My question is: In order to return a variable with a different type than the variable being reduced, **is it only necessary to assert the type of the initial value on a reducer if the arguments are already being infered?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are missing a line in the first code snippet; `reduce` is not properly closed...

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that bolded question, other than to say that the compiler is picking a bad overload.  Arguably the "right" way to do this (answering the question in the title) is neither to assert nor to annotate, but to *explicitly specify* the type argument for the `reduce()` method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgQBvm).  Does that answer your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz in a reply to notify me)

Comment: Thank you @caTS, I already added the missing line.

Comment: Thank you, @jcalz. It works well.
Could you please explain why this should be the right way? I'm new in TypeScript town.

Comment: @jcalz don't let my answer deter you. They are _always_ better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

With `reduce` I often find it best to explicitly pass the result type as the generic type parameter. Then the initial argument and the callback function all get typed properly for you. I find this often removes a great deal of the type errors you usually get with calling `reduce` because Typescript knows exactly how the *completed* reduce result is typed before it starts.

```
const availablePromos = promo.reduce<ICartTotal[]>((acc, cur) => {
    return [
        ...acc,
        {
            type: "discount",
            title: cur.label,
            price: cur.total
        }
    ]
}, [])
// availablePromos is ICartTotal[]
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221017#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGE5TKyBbAJQgGcAHAexGJQG8BYAKGWeWIGsBXALlbClADmAbkYtkpfknQALOCAEQeAI3LkANhDkimLCcCQ8QHPEujaxYcmDhrDx01HMs1cU7d7952gL6NGYAE9SFAAVTGwQqxsQoJQAXmQAImJpYFJSQUTkAB8k6wAPLNzEgBNgYgRyDnBE7UZQSFhEFAwsMEjrNWR6HWZA4J4wto7o2Kc+4DANHmI+QXHxSUVkIxMzRm86hkqqMEXyPHIeVuxcCEISCioIAG0AXWQEm4B6ACpkAGUDlBK4a2RXs87ltGDtZsg4AA3ODAFxKDQABSgB3IxEe+0OADooBAShwkAAeE7tKJqe4APgAFJTEAgADTIBAcKAASke5O6ohYOLAzJAyBuXLEzExotpdKFwp6wplyH6y1K5Uq1TAiQlvVlEymyyZUExcIganVmrEegMjOZmMsnUlYl8GruGwZ9xZQA)